# selecting from dropdown menu with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, menu, dropdown

Im trying to select a dropdown with selenium in python.
I cant get it working. I have tried "clicking" on different links via the xpath and it works. But I can't figure out the drop down menu.

This is the code I have tried using:

```
path = r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("http://elpris.dk")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btnSelectProfile"]""").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage is written using Angular JS, which loads data dynamically. So, use WebDriverWait so that the page gets loaded properly.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

path = r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("http://elpris.dk")
delay = 15
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, delay)
try:
    elem = wait.until(
           EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'btnSelectProfile')))
    elem.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Another option is to add some sleep to wait for the data to get loaded properly like below:

```
import time
path = r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("http://elpris.dk")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btnSelectProfile"]""").click()
```

Then the click will work.